# HTML Form Post to Remote Destination - Google Analytics Referral

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have a form on my WordPress site that posts to a SalesForce URL.

When the form is submitted, the post happens to SaleForce, the user is directed to the SalesForce URL briefly and then returns to the WP site.

Analytics is wrongly tracking leads from Ads as if they are coming from SalesForce. I have excluded the SalesForce domain in my Analytics. However, I'm not sure if what I've done is the best practice.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Yes, excluding a referral is a best practice for example for payment gateways in an e-commerce (i.e. paypal.com). In this way the traffic from paypal.com (when you return after the payment) will be recognized in Google Analytics as direct traffic, so the session is not interrupted and the source remains the original one (i.e. organic or ads). The same thing makes sense with your case and SalesForce.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response. I did this change and tested by clicking on one of the Ads. I submitted a query and waited to see what Analytics would pick up. I picked up the event, however, it doesn't seem to link this event to the Paid Search channel. Any ideas why?

Comment: What source / medium is attributed to this event?

Comment: The lead wasn't captured. The browser I tested with blocked the events. I think it's working now. Excluding the domain did the trick. Thanks for your assistance.